# JavaScript code to create dynamic HREFs & Anchor Text from XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing, anchor, href

I'd like to be able to create `href` links in a div by using `JavaScript` to access an `XML` file that contains a directory structure. I'd also like to show the file name as the Anchor Text for each of the links. The `html` (with inline JavaScript), xml files and content files that the links will be refrencing will be synced automatically from a Windows server to `Android` tablets so no server side code can be used.

I've managed to setup an automated task on the server that runs some Java code to create the XML file/Windows directory structure. This then gets synced down to the Android device along with the content and html files.
The number of links displayed in the div will change as new files get added to the folder and old ones get removed.

An extract of the XML file can be accessed by clicking the link below.
From a bit of research it seems I will have to use xpath, as from the XML below I want to create the href links for all of the files that have an absolutePath attribute that begins with

> "C:\MyFolder\Clients\Client1 (114)\Planograms\".

I then want the Anchor Text of the link to display the file name for each document so the user knows which is which.

Any help is very much appreciated.

[Example XML File](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8673550/example.xml)

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a front end developer.

Comment: Thanks Jared but unfortunately it's not an option at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add a valid XML header to the file, e.g. `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
Are you using a browser to run the Javascript?
You may want to use jQuery in this case (http://jquery.com).
Your HTML and Javascript file could look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<ul id="filelist">
</ul>
    <script>
$.ajax({
url: "http://yourajaxservice",
cache: false
}).done(function( xml ) {
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    $xml.find( "directory" ).each(function() {
            $(this).find("file").each(function() {
                    var currentFileName=$(this).attr("name");
                    var currentPath=$(this).attr("absolutePath");
                    if (currentPath.startsWith("C:\MyFolder\Clients\Client1 (114)\Planograms\")) {
                        $("#filelist").append("<li><a href='"+currentPath+"'>"+currentFileName+"</a></li>");
                   }
           });
   });

});

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great thanks Jorn. My XML file does have a valid header, it was only an extract that I linked to. I will look into jquery thanks.

Comment: Hi Jorn, I cannot seem to get this to work. Where do I reference my xml filename please and what is your reference to AJAX for please? "$.ajax({
url: "http://yourajaxservice",
cache: false
})."